# Chrome Extension - open tab without images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have built a Chrome Extension that opens urls for html parsing in a new tab. Everything works fine but I'd like to optimize the loading speed by stripping images before the page is loaded.

So far I call the tab this way:

```js
function CreateTab(createProperties, shop_list) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.tabs.create(createProperties, tab => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        reject(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError));
      } else {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
          file: 'GetSource.js',
        }, async function(results) {
          my parsing code here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When executeScript is called, it's already too late, the page is there. Is there a way to execute a script before the page is loaded so that I can remove images before getting the html ?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **chrome.webRequest** API (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) with **onBeforeRequest** 
which fires when a request is about to occur. This event is sent before any TCP connection is made and can be used to cancel or redirect requests. Something like this should prevent .jpg images from loading:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
          return {cancel: details.url.indexOf(".jpg") != -1};
        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking"]);
```

Comment: It's even better to provide the URL pattern like `urls: '*://*/*.jpg'` and `types: ['image']` and `tabId: yourActualTabId` to avoid triggering the listener on other URLs.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I thought of using a regex to capture all image types but it doesn't seem to work, I tried this: "*://*/*.(jpg|gif)". Is there a way to block all images no matter the extension ? Thanks